# How to repeat and delay calls to APIs through D3

Tags: javascript, json, api, d3.js

it is not hard to call get data from API once, but how to make it continuous process. Like generate calls every 5 seconds to some API? Is there a way I could use `.delay()` on `d3.json()`?

Here is the code that executes this process only once:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
d3.json("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing different (as a function I mean) in `d3.json()` or the other D3 fetch functions. You can put it inside a `setInterval` or, since this is a D3 code, inside a `d3.interval`.

Here is a simple demo, instead of your API I'm using an API that generates random values, so you can see that it works:

```js
getData();
d3.interval(getData, 5000);

function getData() {
  d3.json("https://randomuser.me/api/").then(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.results[0].name));
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I'm calling the function the regular way the first time, otherwise it would be called only after 5 seconds. Regarding the delay, if it's called just once, you can use `setTimeout` (or `d3.timeout`).

Comment: Thank you. It really didn't look that complicated :)